# Invalid configuration found for parameter 'resource' in component

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am working on a Mule project on runtime version 4.3.0.
I am trying to externalize my DataWeave script into a DWL file as below:

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="6aeea8a6-1578-4991-ac5a-ed7ebfd1566b">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload resource="dataweave/dataweave-script.dwl" />
            </ee:message>
</ee:transform>
```

The Mule project is getting deployed successfully but when a request is made to the associated endpoint, the following exception is being thrown:

```
ERROR 2020-10-27 15:49:54,703 [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.14: [hello-world-api].hello-world-apiFlow.CPU_LITE @4e834155] [event: f48ac961-183d-11eb-8933-00090ffe0001] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Invalid configuration found for parameter 'resource' in component [set-payload]: 
 Couldn't find resource: dataweave/dataweave-script.dwl neither on classpath or in file system.
Element               : hello-world-apiFlow/processors/0 @ hello-world-api:hello-world-api.xml:17 (hello-worldSub_Flow)
Element XML           : <flow-ref doc:name="hello-worldSub_Flow" doc:id="9069f14e-649b-4d29-b09b-220d9cf934f4" name="hello-worldSub_Flow"></flow-ref>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Invalid configuration found for parameter 'resource' in component [set-payload]: 
 Couldn't find resource: dataweave/dataweave-script.dwl neither on classpath or in file system
********************************************************************************
```

I have also tried using the following instead, with same error being thrown:

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="6aeea8a6-1578-4991-ac5a-ed7ebfd1566b">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload resource="classpath://dataweave/dataweave-script.dwl" />
            </ee:message>
</ee:transform>
```

Comment: In what subdirectory of the source project is the file dataweave-script.dwl? Are you trying in standalone or Studio?

Comment: The associated DWL file is stored in dataweave package inside the src/main/resources

Comment: is it at `src/main/resources/dataweave/dataweave-script.dwl`? Please share the exact path.

Comment: Yes, the complete path for the script file is src/main/resources/dataweave/dataweave-script.dwl

Comment: Did you stop and restart the execution after adding the file?

Comment: Yes, I have tried:
1. Restarting the application after adding the DWL file.
2. Clearing application data in run configurations.
3. Created another application with similar code.

None of the above have helped resolve the issue.

Comment: You can see the file within the project explorer?

Comment: Yes @maddestroyer7, the DWL script is visible in the project explorer